# how to edit paragraphs in html page and store it in mysql database?

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-boot

By using Spring Boot, java & html, I have created a small website where I given sliding images, normal images and some content with paragraphs. I wanted to put edit button and give access to everyone for editing the page. by clicking edit button user can edit the page and after editing the page, the page should updated and the information should store in mysql database. can anyone please tell me, how can i edit the page and store all type of data in mysql database.

Comment: Please show us some work of your own and point out specific problems. StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

> by clicking edit button user can edit the page and after editing the page, the page should updated and the information should store in mysql database. can anyone please tell me, how can i edit the page and store all type of data in mysql database.

So you are looking for a technology that transfers the users' data to your server (and later on access it again).
For that, you can use a so called REST-Service. [This source](https://stackify.com/rest-api-tutorial/) defines REST as following:

"*Even though REpresentational State Transfer, also known as REST, is often referred to as a protocol, it’s an architectural style. It defines how applications communicate over the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP). Applications that use REST are loosely-coupled and transfer information quickly and efficiently. While REST doesn’t define data formats, it’s usually associated with exchanging JSON or XML documents between a client and a server.*"